# Angularjs populate Select2 plugin with values from http request

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, http, select

I'm new in angularjs and I have a problem with values from http request. I use this values to populate an Select field but I can't set the default value (for example the first element of array).
This is my javascript code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('freeUserController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'users'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.users = response.data.result;
        $scope.selectedItem = $scope.users[0];
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
    });
});
```

Instead on my html code I have

```
<label>Username</label> <select class="form-control select2"
    style="width: 100%;" name="user" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="user.username for user in users">
</select>
```

If I change the result of http request with static array all works fine.
Are you know why I have this problem?

Before I used this thymeleaf code with success:

```
<div class="form-group" id=existingUser>
    <label>Username</label> <select class="form-control select2"
    style="width: 100%;" th:field="*{user}">
    <option th:each="user: ${users}" th:value="${user.username}"
    th:text="${user.username}"></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

this is the debug image

[image: debug image]

I tought was a problem of plugin, but with static array it works like with thymeleaf

Comment: try it
http://jsfiddle.net/sinkz/HB7LU/23128/

Comment: the problem is with the http call

Comment: try `console.log(response.data.result)`. What is displayed?

Comment: I added browser debug image

Answer (score 1):

Your using `user.username` to display and in *script* your assigning complete *user Objec*t like this

```
$scope.selectedItem = $scope.users[0];
```

change this to

```
$scope.selectedItem = $scope.users[0].username;
```

This should work now

Answer (score 0):

In **ng-model** give like this and try.

```
ng-model="selectedItem.username"
```

Otherwise in controller change like below:

```
$scope.selectedItem=$scope.users[0].username;
```

Comment: Can you post your response? What u r getting from back end?

Comment: if  I set $scope.users[0].username I must not use selectedItem.username in ng-model. In javascript the variables are setted fine, but the default value of select is empty string

Answer (score 0):

should can easily give the select an "ng-init" like so:

```
<select class="form-control select2" ng-init="selectedItem = users[0]"
style="width: 100%;" name="user" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="user.username for user in users">
```

Sorry for formating

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `user.id as user.username` in `ng-options` directive.

```
<select class="form-control select2"
    style="width: 100%;" name="user" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="user.id as user.username for user in users">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="user.username as user.username for user in users">
          <option value="" selected="selected">{{users[0].m}}</option>
    </select>
```

Controller

```
$scope.selectedItem = $scope.users[0].username;
```

Comment: without the class it works, maybe the problem is between Select2 plugin and angularjs

Comment: it doesn't work, I can try to check if value is selected and let the default value empty